# Node request shows jwt token in console log but can't set in cookie

Tags: express, post

For some reason the response is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.

When I want to set the data in the cookie.

However when I just console log the data, it has no problems.

I've got the following request:

registerRoute.route("/register").post(async (req, res) => {
const { username, password, email } = req.body;

try {
await axios
.post("url", {
username: "###",
email: "###",
password: "###",
})
.then((response) => {
// Handle success.
res.status(200);
res.send("Registration complete");

```
    if (response.data.jwt) {
      res.cookie("secureCookie", response.data.jwt, {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: dayjs().add(30, "days").toDate(),
      });
    }
    console.log("User token", response.data.jwt);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error.
    res.status(400);
    if (error.response.data.message[0].messages[0].message) {
      res.send(error.response.data.message[0].messages[0].message);
    }
    console.log(
      "An error occurred:",
      error.response.data.message[0].messages[0].message
    );
  });
```

} catch (e) {
res
.status(400)
.send("An error occurred:", e.response.data.message[0].messages[0]);
}
});

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! The cookie "expires" was faulty. The error just confused me because it said cannot read property 'data' of undefined. In the end it had nothing to do with 'data'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).